# checking which object an iterator is a position in

Tags: c++

I have the following List class:

```
typedef int Elem;               // list base element type
  class NodeList {              // node-based list
  private:
    struct Node {               // a node of the list
      Elem elem;                // element value
      Node* prev;               // previous in list
      Node* next;               // next in list
    };
  public:
    class Iterator {                // an iterator for the list
    public:
      Elem& operator*();            // reference to the element
      bool operator==(const Iterator& p) const; // compare positions
      bool operator!=(const Iterator& p) const;
      Iterator& operator++();           // move to next position
      Iterator& operator--();           // move to previous position
      friend class NodeList;            // give NodeList access
    private:
      Node* v;                  // pointer to the node
      Iterator(Node* u);            // create from node
    };
  public:
    NodeList();                 // default constructor
    int size() const;               // list size
    bool empty() const;             // is the list empty?
    Iterator begin() const;         // beginning position
    Iterator end() const;           // (just beyond) last position
    void insertFront(const Elem& e);        // insert at front
    void insertBack(const Elem& e);     // insert at rear
    void insert(const Iterator& p, const Elem& e); // insert e before p
    void eraseFront();              // remove first
    void eraseBack();               // remove last
    void erase(const Iterator& p);      // remove p
  private:                  // data members
    int     n;                  // number of items
    Node*   header;             // head-of-list sentinel
    Node*   trailer;                // tail-of-list sentinel
  };
```

My code does not do any checking to determine whether a given position (iterator object) is actually a member of a particular list. For example, if *p* is a position in list S and I call T.insert(p,e) on a different list T, then I'd actually be adding the element to S just before p. How can I change my NodeList implementation to disallow such a misuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would mean a bit of memory overhead but if you store the head of each list in all nodes you can check if the heads are the same, then it's probably the same list.

Or if you prefer cpu overhead over memory overhead, loop through the prev-links to find the head of both lists and compare them as above.

So it depends on which kind of overhead you prefer.